# angularjs $watch is not working in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to load data in directive by using one-way binding here is the code.

```
  <nav-directive depts="dummyData"></nav-directive>

APP.directive('navDirective', navDirective);
```

here is directive

```
function navDirective($state, navigationService,$rootScope) {

return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { depts: '=' },
    templateUrl: '/app/shared/common-directives/navigation/navigation.view.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            $rootScope.$watch('depts', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            // or $watchCollection if students is an array
            if (newVal) {
               console.log('in Dir');
               console.log(scope.depts)
            }
        },true);


    }
};
}
```

scope.depts is undefined when data updated by conroller.

Comment: Why `$rootScope.$watch`? try `scope.$watch`. I guess there's just no `depts` in the `$rootScope` to be watched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `$scope.$watch('someString')` tells Angular to watch the value of the variable named `someString` *in the given* `$scope`. Here you use it on the `$rootScope`, so it will look for a variable `depts` defined on the rootScope, and it won't find one because `depts` is only defined on `scope`.

So just use `scope.$watch('depts')`.

Comment: I tried it wasn't working but now its working by using scope. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this, its working. Use [scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dummyData = 'World';
});

app.directive('navDirective', function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { depts: '=' },
    template: '<div>test</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.$watch('depts', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            // or $watchCollection if students is an array
            if (newVal) {
               console.log('in Dir');
               console.log(scope.depts)
            }
        },true);


    }
};
});
```

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <nav-directive depts="dummyData"></nav-directive>
  depts value:  <input ng-model="dummyData"/> 
  </body>
```